# Keep Kotlin console application running forever

Tags: loops, kotlin, events, console, forever

I have an event driven Kotlin console application utilizing the [Paho MQTT client](https://github.com/eclipse/paho.mqtt.java).

I successfully connect via

```
val serverURI = "${config.mqtt.protocol}://${config.mqtt.host}:${config.mqtt.port}"
client = MqttClient(serverURI, config.mqtt.client_id, MemoryPersistence())
client.connect()
```

The application remains running for a couple of seconds, then it ends by itself.

I also registered already a signal handler. This would ends the application via CTRL + C.

```
Signal.handle(Signal("INT")) { stopApplication() }
Signal.handle(Signal("TERM")) { stopApplication() }
```

Is there a better way to keep the application running instead of using

```
while (true) { }
```

Comment: I'd suggest to use something like `Spring Boot Command Line Runner` or any other library that does this.

Comment: @Alex.T Thank you for the hint. That seems to be working. Of course it add alot of overhead for this task.

Comment: the minimum requirements are around 70MB of memory, for the embeded Tomcat servlet. Unless you add other spring stuff, I'd say it will use an extra of max 100MB. This is big/small depending on how much your app used to use before, and also what you are running it on.